# Как убрать из проекта Xamarin.Forms packages, которые не активны, но svn их видит

Tags: svn, xamarin-studio

На Mac работаю в Xamarin Studio. svn пользуюсь через терминал. Обновил некоторые packages до предлагаемых nuget'ом. Но пришлось откатить до старых версий через svn. Но теперь svn status пишет, что старые версии библиотек остались и не прикреплены к проекту. Статус "?". На попытки удаления через svn пишет "is not under version control", что и предполагает статус "?".

Может кто-то подскажет как удалить эти файлы? В каталоге с проектом физически не нашел расположения. Критичности никакой в этом нет, но просто мазолит глаза, особенно, когда нужно большой список файлов коммитить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала нашел корявое решение: в самом проекте отредактировал файл, в котором указаны версии библиотек. Указал текущими версиями библиотек - версии неудаляющихся файлов, потом они стали доступны для удаления в проекте.

А затем, оказалось, что все библиотеки сложены в отдельной папке, просто она выше по директории, чем папка подпроектов. В ней все библиотеки, которые используются во всех подпроектах. Там можно просто ручками удалить все лишнее.